# call user control and pass custom property with allowed values

Tags: c#, properties, controls

i would like to call a user control(ascx) in one of my aspx page and pass a custom property with allowed predefined list of values, to it.
example:

```
<uc:MyCustomControl runat="server" CustomProperty="One|Two|Three" />
```

the {One, Two, Three} should come in Visual studio intellisence dropdown, similar to "Treu|False" values for IsVisible property.

Comment: define CustomProperty as enum !!

Answer (score 0):

Use an enum on your control:

```
public enum CustomPropertyOptions
{
     One,
     Two,
     Three
}

public CustomPropertyOptions CustomProperty
{
     get; set;
}
```

Comment: Please consider marking this as the answer, if it solved your problem.

Comment: I tried, but i don't have 15 points, which is eligibility of marking responses as answers.